# PHP foreach over uniquely styled divs

Tags: php, api, foreach

I'm trying to pull information from instagram and twitter, and display the information as a collection of square and rectangle boxes arranged on screen.

I was using a foreach statement to display the content, but because the containing divs are not consistent in size, I have to end the foreach statement and start a new one. The content of the new foreach is exactly the same as the content of the previous. I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way and would appreciate any push in the right direction.

The block of code below displays the first 4 most recent instagram photos.

```
    <?php $i = 0; foreach ($instagram_data->data as $latest_post): if (++$i == 5) break; ?>
    <div class="engage-block"><img src="<?= $latest_post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"></div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

After that, I display the latest twitter content.

```
    <div class="engage-horizontal engage-block"><span>"<?php echo $latest_tweet->text ?>"</span></div>
```

And then I repeat another foreach similar to the first to display more instagram content. This however repeats the exact same content from the code above (shows the latest 4 photos instead of the 4 photos after the original photos).

Answer (score 0):

You could put a variable in the foreach to make the twitter div if it's the fifth, like this

```
<?php 
$i = 0; foreach ($instagram_data->data as $latest_post){
?>
if ($i==5){?>
        <div class="engage-horizontal engage-block"><span>"<?php echo $latest_tweet->text ?>"</span></div>
$i=0;
}
else{?>
<div class="engage-block"><img src="<?= $latest_post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"></div>
<?php
}

$i++;
} ?>
```